# in Java, how to monitor several log files concurrently

Tags: java, logging

i want to monitor several log files concurrently .How to do in java ?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096404/is-there-a-sophisticated-file-system-monitor-for-java-which-is-freeware-or-open-s

Comment: What do you mean by 'monitor'?

Comment: with threads? However, it's not entirely clear to me what you mean by 'monitor'

Comment: if it is just monitoring the logs you want to do, then on Linux, you can use tail -f and specify all the log files you want to monitor

Comment: possible duplicate of [in java taillistener, how to handle more log files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039923/in-java-taillistener-how-to-handle-more-log-files)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to understand what you want to do, so I will guess :)

Use the Apache Commons IO class named [Tailer](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html) to tail the files that you want to keep track of. (If reading from them is what you want to do). The javadoc for the class has examples of how to use it with threads.

Comment: yes ..i want to display the log message when log messages are updated in log file.

Comment: Also when i am using Tailer api,i facing the following problem.please look in to this .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039923/in-java-taillistener-how-to-handle-more-log-files